# Cine footage from Saturn V launches

Tags: saturn-v, camera

How did they recover the film showing the separation of the S II stage from the S 1C and the tumbling interstage faring which attached the two stages? The camera which is attached to the S II has a view pointing down showing the sequence, yet by all the information I have come across says the S II was destroyed and not recovered. There was no TDRSS system to relay video in those days and the imagery is of film quality. I have seen no account of a film capsule being released from the stage during the launch. There is also a camera view on top of the S II showing the separation of the S IV B.

Answer (score 19):

The cameras were ejected from the stages and parachuted into the sea. If you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTGk3UM-IOU) you can see cameras being ejected from stages at exactly 5:00 and 7:42.

There's also a good discussion on [Collect Space](http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum29/HTML/001228.html) including a picture of one of the modules after it has been fished out of the ocean.

[image]

Comment: Well thanks for that. For 50 years I have wondered how those pictures were obtained and in all the reading I have done on the subject I have never seen a reference to capsules being ejected from the S II. You learn something new every day. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

There were ejectable camera pods, here's a picture of one.

[image]

Used on Saturn I-Bs and Saturn Vs through Apollo 8.

Full writeup [here](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/camerapods/camerapodessay.html), other good info [here](https://gwsbooks.blogspot.com/2017/07/s-iis-ivb-staging-was-never-videoed.html).