# What did the Saturn V interstage camera capsules look like?

Tags: saturn-v, camera

Apollo 4 and 6 each carried a pair of high-speed cameras on the second stage of the Saturn V launch vehicle.  They filmed the separation of the first stage and its interstage ring, after which the capsules containing the cameras were ejected, splashed down in the ocean, and recovered.  Footage from these cameras is often used in documentaries.

**What did these camera capsules look like?**  Photographs before or after the mission, or drawings are acceptable.

[image: Still image of burning interstage ring from Apollo 4]

Picture taken from [Why did the Saturn V stage fairing appear to burn after separation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3987/26446)

Comment: The cameras ran at four times normal speed to show the events in slow motion. A moderate high speed.

Comment: There are pictures in the answers to this question: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37358/6944  It's not exactly a duplicate question, I guess.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: I *did* try several searches here before posting the question, so it's not easy to find.

Comment: Interesting, for me it's the first hit for 'camera pod'. Maybe that's because I wrote one of the answers. The search engine here is...weird. I usually give up and use google.

Comment: **Self-closing** as duplicate found by @OrganicMarble.  By closing rather than deleting the question, it will be easier for future searches to find.